# Prove there exists a 2x2 entirely black or white square.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given a 200x200 board containing black and white squares prove there exists a 2x2 sub square that is entirely black or entirely white. The total # of squares is 40000, there are 199x199 squares of 2x2. The #Black-#White = 404 or the #Black+#White = 40000. How can I go about this? I appreciate the input. Thank you.

Comment: It is simply not true. If the squares with the least frequent colour make up $25$ % or more of the total, you can always arrange them so that every $2$ by $2$ sub-square is made up of squares of both colours. In your example the difference between black and white is small, so it easily satisfies the $25$ % criterion.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1261370/18398

Comment: If you are not sure if a statement is true, you should state that it is a conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

Let each of the even rows have cells that alternate black and white.  Then any $2\times2$ square has two squares in an even row, and those squares are one black, one white.  The squares in the odd rows can be any colour, to allow $\sharp$Black-$\sharp$White=404.
Perhaps the question was to show that the corners of some square were all black or all white?

Comment: Yes.  Fixed now.